# Array length doesn't change

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filtering

i've got a problem. I'm trying to make data search from API.
The problem is that `{people.length === 0 && <p>No data</p>}` is not working. When i `console.log people.length` the length value doesn't change when i'm typing. Where's the problem?

Here's my code:

```
const PeopleSearch = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(swapi);
      const transformedPeople = response.data.results.sort((a, b) =>
        a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
      );
      setPeople(transformedPeople);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const searchHandler = (event) => {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search by name..."
        onChange={searchHandler}
      />
      <section>
        {loading ? (
          <Loading />
        ) : (
          <PeopleList
            people={people.filter(({ name }) => {
              if (name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
                return people;
              }
            })}
          />
        )}
        {people.length === 0 && <p>No data</p>}
      </section>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only calling `setPeople` once, on mount, with the `useEffect(() => { ... }, [])` - so `people.length` will remain the same once the API call completes. You need to use the filtered array both for the PeopleList prop and the `No data` check.

You should also tweak your `filter`, since it only cares about whether its return value is truthy or not.

```
const filteredPeople = people.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()));
return (
    <>
      <Input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search by name..."
        onChange={searchHandler}
      />
      <section>
        {loading ? (
          <Loading />
        ) : (
          <PeopleList
            people={filteredPeople}
          />
        )}
        {filteredPeople.length === 0 && !loading && <p>No data</p>}
      </section>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: @CertainPefrormance Thanks! It's working now! :)